# Virtualenv python not recognizing .pth for custom site-packages

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv

I installed a new virtual env with python3.6. After checking its site packages (`python3.6 -m site --user-site`) I was pointed to `/Users/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages`.

I added a file named `custom.pth` with the contents:

```
/Users/username/Python Files/Packages
```

but for some reason, it still fails to recognize our inhouse packages. However, I have the exact same .pth file for the system's python3.6 and it works without a hitch. Is there something else I can try?

Answer (score 0):

It finally worked when I placed the .pth file into the `<venv folder>/lib/python3.6/site-packages/` directory. Perhaps it's an issue with the activated venv overriding the python's site-packages

Answer (score -1):

Python virtual environments are intended to isolate packages from both global and user `site-packages`. User `site-packages` are not available to Python in a virtual environment. Compare `python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"` before and after activating a venv. Hence their `.pth` files are not processed.

Outside of a venv `.pth` files from the user `site-packages` are processed.